# How to manage two MongoDB Collections in react-native

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i want to make two collections. one for `Users` and one for their `Transactions`

my Schema.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const adsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    item : String,
    server : String,
    price : String,
})

mongoose.model("ads",adsSchema)
```

my app.js :

```
const Ads = mongoose.model("ads")

app.post('/send-data',(req,res) => {
    const ads = new Ads({
        item : req.body.item,
        price : req.body.price,
    })
    ads.save()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        res.send("success")
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(,err)
    })
})
```

so what i need is to make another app.post ? like `app.post('/transactions',...`

Comment: You can add an object in the `User` schema for their transactions. Example: `Transactions: {...}`

Comment: @Tyler2P , I don't want to mix them up. Transaction has it's own rules and objects

Answer (score 0):

Just ref the transactions schema in the user schema.
example:

```
 const userSchema = Schema({
      ...
      transactions: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Transaction' }]
    });
```

you can also do the other way around, and ref the user in the transaction schema.